# automatically number consecutively the rel attribute of an a-tag

Tags: jquery, flexslider, relation, rel

I want to automaticallly number consecutively the `rel` attribute of an HTML a-tag with javascript or jquery...

for example:

```
<a rel="0" class="slide_thumb" href="#">
<a rel="1" class="slide_thumb" href="#">
<a rel="2" class="slide_thumb" href="#">
<a rel="3" class="slide_thumb" href="#">
```

It's for the flexslider. I have integrated flexslider in shopware.
I used it as a banner-slider.

I need a very simple code

Comment: Note that this is a misuse of the `rel` attribute (it’s invalid in HTML5). You might want to use a `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all element with class `slide_thumb` using `.each()` and add attribute inside it using `.attr()`

```
$(".slide_thumb").each(function(i) {
   $(this).attr("rel",i);
});
```

Comment: @ibrah welcome :) please upvote and mark it correct if its useful

Answer (score 1):

You can easy do it with `each` loop. The first callback parameter is the element index, starting by zero. So it is perfect for you needs.

```
$("a.slide_thumb").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("rel", i);
});
```